# setup a script to run in background in cronjob

Tags: shell, cron, ksh

I want to put a simple command in the background in crontab (Linux). But my attempts failed for some reason. Am I missing something here? I know cron means running in the background.

My command works manually though `- nohup script.sh &`

My cronjob is:

`0 15 * * 5 /absolute path to script.sh`

And I've tried this:

`- 0 15 * * 5 nohup /absolute path to script.sh &` but still doesn't work.

I also made sure permissions for the file is `744`.

Comment: Cron runs in the background -- yes, but conversely that doesn't mean everything that needs to run in the background needs cron.  Anyway, let's assume your script does -- you gave the cronjob line, but not the script.

Comment: perms should be `755` (typically). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron for the most common cron solutions. Good luck.

Comment: Note that the line "0 15 * * 5 nohup /absolute path .." means run at 5th day of the week at 15:00". I hope you tested with something more frequent than that...

Comment: it seems you are trying to execute the script At 15:00 every Friday, so it would be really nice if you provide what are you looking for

Comment: the script is run is "script.sh" which run complex jobs underneath. but my question is how does I specify "nohup script.sh &" in a crontab.

Comment: its time for me to run it, appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Start learning `cron` with simple commands like `date > /tmp/teja_test.log`.

Comment: Firstly, the user-id to run the cron job may NOT be the same as your user-id.  So, please make that user-id can run your script.  Secondly, cron job will NOT call the default login .profile or .bashrc files or else.  So, those setup done by .profile or .bashrc will NOT present when executing your script.

Comment: the cronjob is configured with the user that owns my script and has permissions.

Comment: Did you edit the crontab using `crontab -e` ? That provides some basic checking.

Comment: If `you are not using `crontab -e`, are you using the` /etc/cron.d` directory or the `/etc/crontab` instead? There might be files like `/etc/cron.allow` and `/etc/cron.deny that control whether the userud is allowed to run cronjobs.

Comment: I am using crontab -e in my case